# If combobox equal to empty, do not copy userform data to excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have create 2 sub function like this:

```
Sub Product1()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")

lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
With ws

If IsEmpty(UserForm5.ComboBox5.Value) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = UserForm5.TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox3.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox4.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox5.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = UserForm5.TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = UserForm5.TextBox5.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = UserForm5.TextBox6.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = UserForm5.TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = UserForm5.TextBox7.Value

End If

End With

End Sub


Sub Product2()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")

lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
With ws

If IsEmpty(UserForm5.ComboBox6.Value) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = UserForm5.TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox3.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox4.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox6.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = UserForm5.TextBox9.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = UserForm5.TextBox11.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = UserForm5.TextBox12.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = UserForm5.TextBox10.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = UserForm5.TextBox8.Value
End If

End With

End Sub
```

I was wondering that, if my combobox6 is empty, it should not transfer the data for to exel sheet.

What I faced now is if the combobox6 is empty( did not select any value), it will still copy all the data to the excel sheet.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If IsEmpty(UserForm5.ComboBox5.Value) Then
```

to

```
If UserForm5.ComboBox5.Value = "" Then
```

And make the same sort of change to the Product2 sub.

Answer (score 0):

If the combo box is "empty" then checking its value will give you an empty string.

```
Sub Product1()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    With ws
        If UserForm5.ComboBox5.Value <> "" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = UserForm5.TextBox1.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox2.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox3.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox4.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox1.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox5.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = UserForm5.TextBox2.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = UserForm5.TextBox5.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = UserForm5.TextBox6.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = UserForm5.TextBox4.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = UserForm5.TextBox7.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub Product2()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    With ws
        If UserForm5.ComboBox6.Value <> "" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = UserForm5.TextBox1.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox2.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox3.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox4.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox1.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = UserForm5.ComboBox6.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = UserForm5.TextBox9.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = UserForm5.TextBox11.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = UserForm5.TextBox12.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = UserForm5.TextBox10.Value
            .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = UserForm5.TextBox8.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```